# Duplication of data on browser refresh - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I'm using [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) and Nodejs to load a list of options into a dropdown box on my site. Each time the page is refreshed I get duplication of the data in the dropdown box. How can this be prevented. I hope my question is clear.

You  can see how I use Mustache in the html code snippet below;

```
<div class="cd-filter-block">
                <h4>Branches</h4>
                <div class="cd-filter-content">
                    <div class="cd-select cd-filters">
                        <select class="filter" name="selectThis" type="radio" id="branches">
                            {{#branches}}
                                <option>{{name}}</option>
                            {{/branches}}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is the Nodejs code;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var glob = require('glob');
var mustache = require('Mustache');
var mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');

// Register '.mustache' extension with The Mustache Express
app.engine('mustache', mustacheExpress());
app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static('public'));

//mustache templates
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var view = {
        'branches' : listBranches(),
    'gdc' : listFiles('../branches/BR/Desktop/other/'),
        'san' : listFiles('../branches/BR/other/'),
        'gmc' : listFiles('../branches/BR/Mobile/other/'),
        'filter' : listFiles1('../branches/BR/Mobile/other/')
    }
    res.render('index', view);
});
3
//listBranches
var fs = require('fs');
var glob = require('glob');
var path = '../branches/other/' + '*';
var filelist = [];

function listBranches() {
  var files =  glob.sync(path).filter(isFolder);

  for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    filelist.push({
      name:   files[i].split('/')[3],
    });
  };

  return filelist;
}

function listFiles(path) {

    var filelist2 = [];
  var files = glob.sync(path + '**').filter(isFile);

  for (var i = files.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    filelist2.push({
        "filename" : getFilename(files[i]),
                "path" : files[i]
      });
    };

    return filelist2;
}

function getFilename(path) {
    var parts = path.split('/');
    return parts[parts.length-1];
}

function isFolder(path) {
  return fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory();
}

function isFile(path) {
  return fs.lstatSync(path).isFile();
}

//filters
function listFiles1(path) {
    var filelist = [];
    var files =  glob
        .sync(path + '**')
        .filter(isFile);

    for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        filelist.push(
            {"filename" : createURL('test1','brand','test3','test4',getFilename(files[i])),
             "path" : files[i]
            });
            console.log(createURL('test1','brand','test3','test4',getFilename(files[i])));
    };

    return filelist;
}

function isFile(path) {
    return fs.lstatSync(path).isFile();
}

function getFilename(path) {
    var parts = path.split('/');
    return parts[parts.length-1];
}

function splitFile(file,part) {
    var parts2 = file.split('.');
    return parts2[part];

}



function createURL(filter1, filter2, filter3, section, file) {


    var branch = filter1;
    var brand = filter2;
    var channel = filter3;


    return 'http://' + '--' + channel + '.' + brand + '.' + 'local:8085' + '/' + '/' + file


}

//run app
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('App running on port 3000!')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `listBranches()` is called on your server, you are adding more items to the `filelist` array so items will accumulate in that variable and since `listBranches()` returns that variable, each time it is called, it will return a longer and longer array.

It's not entirely clear to me what your code is trying to do, but you can at least fix that problem by changing this:

```
var filelist = [];

function listBranches() {
  var files =  glob.sync(path).filter(isFolder);

  for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    filelist.push({
      name:   files[i].split('/')[3],
    });
  };

  return filelist;
}
```

to this:

```
function listBranches() {
  var filelist = [];
  var files =  glob.sync(path).filter(isFolder);

  for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    filelist.push({
      name:   files[i].split('/')[3],
    });
  };

  return filelist;
}
```

Remember that module level or global variables on your server persist from one request to the next and are shared by all requests.  So, don't use module level variables unless that is the intended behavior.

Comment: Many thanks, I really appreciate your answer. It worked and I now understand how to do it for future reference. Much appreciated :)